# Unable to install libfreetype6:i386 Ubuntu 14.10 64-Bit

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

When trying to install some applications via Ubuntu software centre I am getting the error:

```
cannot install libfreetype6:i386
```

So I tried to install it via terminal, and got this result:

```
bfalcon@lappy:~$ sudo apt-get install libfreetype6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-keyring : Depends: gcr (>= 3.4) but it is not going to be installed
indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or 
                               gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                            ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: gnome-bluetooth but it is not going to be installed or
                            ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
indicator-network : Depends: unity8 (>= 8.00+14.10.20140806) but it is not going to be installed
libfreetype6:i386 : Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
qtcontact5-galera : Depends: address-book-service (= 0.1.1+14.10.20140930-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
signon-ui : Depends: signon-ui-x11 but it is not going to be installed or
                  ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts (>= 0.4) but it is not going to be installed

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have tried a searching around a bit, but haven't come up with any solutions.

Comment: Did you try to install it from Ubuntu Software Center? Search Libfreetype, select and install the one you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command to install all of the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center gnome-control-center ubuntu-system-settings gnome-bluetooth unity8 ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts libpng12-0:i386 address-book-service
```